# Left Operend String Error

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, input

Once i try a simple program, this message shows up:
TypeError: 'in ' requires string as left operand, not tuple
That's the script:

```
Answer = "Yeah", "Yes"
if Answer in input():
    print("Alright!")
```

the message shows once i press run and type one of the variables. In this case, "Yeah" or "Yes".
What should ii'l do?
Yeah ik, im a noobie ;)

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you want to do.

If you want to see if the user's input is one of the values of the tuple, switch the order in your `if` statement:

```
Answer = "Yeah", "Yes"
if input() in Answer:
    print("Alright!")
```

If you want to see if the user's input contains one of the values of the tuple, that is a bit more complicated. The best way is to use list comprehension (or in this case, *tuple*), and the built-in [`any()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) function to turn the resulting collection into a boolean:

```
Answer = "Yeah", "Yes"
if any(word in input() for word in Answer):
    print("Alright!")
```

Comment: But if you don't put the `[ ]`, then it's a generator comprehension and not a list comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

@stybl showed you how to fix your problems, I'll explain your error.

```
Anwser = "Yeah", "Yes"
```

In this line you are making a **tuple**. a tuple is like a list except that you can't modify it after its creation.

The previous code line can be written like this:

```
Answer = ("Yeah", "Yes")
```

In Python the parenthesis aren't necessary but the two lines are the same.
So it makes no sense to check if there is a tuple (a list if you prefer) into a string.

More about tuples [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple).